# ArgumentError - interval is not a valid option - Google Calendar API error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've been trying to troubleshoot the integration of Google's Calendar API with my rails app but can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I've Googled all over the place but couldn't find any mentions of this particular error.

The error is:

```
ArgumentError - interval is not a valid option
retriable (3.0.2) lib/retriable/config.rb:32:in `block in initialize'
retriable (3.0.2) lib/retriable/config.rb:31:in `initialize'
retriable (3.0.2) lib/retriable.rb:18:in `retriable'
google-api-client (0.7.1) lib/google/api_client.rb:595:in `execute!'
google-api-client (0.7.1) lib/google/api_client.rb:330:in `discovery_document'
google-api-client (0.7.1) lib/google/api_client.rb:375:in `discovered_api'
app/services/google_calendar_api.rb:41:in `new_api_session'
app/services/google_calendar_api.rb:11:in `create_event'
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:57:in `create'
```

It's raised at this line:

```
@service = @client.discovered_api('event', 'v3')
```

This is the code I'm using to initialize the api session:

```
# This is in my google_api.rb

class GoogleCalendarAPI

  def initialize(user, params, event)
    @user = user
    @params = params
    @event = event
    @client = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
  end

  def create_event
    if new_api_session
      create_event_object_using_params
      send_google_event_create_request
      update_google_event_id_on_event
    end
  end

private 

def new_api_session
  if @user.access_token?
    @client = Google::APIClient.new
    @client.authorization.access_token  = @user.access_token
    @client.authorization.refresh_token = @user.refresh_token
    @client.authorization.client_id     = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID']
    @client.authorization.client_secret = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
    @client.authorization.grant_type    = 'refresh_token'
    @client.authorization.refresh!
    @service = @client.discovered_api('event', 'v3')
  else
    return
  end
end

# Events crontroller
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  if (event_params[:user_id]).blank?
    @event.user_id = current_user.id
  end

  if params[:send_client_email].present?
    ClientMailer.event_creation_notification(event_params, @event, params, current_user).deliver_now
  end

  # If the user authorized their Google Calendar create the event
  # in their Google Calendar using the API
  if current_user.access_token?
    google_api_session = GoogleCalendarAPI.new(current_user, event_params, @event)
    google_api_session.create_event
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.save
      format.html { redirect_to events_path , notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using the following gems:

```
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'google-api-client', '~0.7.1', require: 'google/api_client'
```

I am able to successfully get the user's access_token and refresh_token as well as provider and uid but for some reason can't initialize the API session.

Let me know if you need any other info and thanks in advance for any guidance or ideas!

Comment: The error is in this code; you should share it: `retriable (3.0.2) lib/retriable/config.rb:32`

Comment: Your error is occurring here: https://github.com/kamui/retriable/blob/master/lib/retriable/config.rb#L32

Comment: Are you configuring `retriable` somewhere? like in an initializer? Seems like this is the issue and you need to change `interval` to `intervals`

Comment: @tuyona0102 Yes, that's how gems work. The point is that your question presumes the error is with Google Calendars. Your issue is with a different library entirely. It would help if you shared the part of the stack trace that is your own code. I suspect engineersmnky is on the right track.

Comment: Voting to close on the grounds that this is merely a typo. Please update your question if you are still getting an error after fixing the typo.

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm not configuring it anywhere. Searched the entire app codebase for "interval" and "retriable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind retriable version to 3.0.1 in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'retriable', '3.0.1'
```

Comment: Hey, it would be nice if you added an explanation or at least links pointing out why this might be a solution.